# Adding highlighted Event to Calendar android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on this new project of mine and I'm trying to add an event to a simple CompactCalendarView on a specific day, my code seems good but the event isn't showing after running the application on my phone!! here's how I added the Event:

```
package calendar.dev.aimlroy.cal;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView;
import com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.domain.Event;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CompactCalendarView calendar;
    TextView t;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendar = (CompactCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        String[] d = {"","","","","","",""};
        calendar.setDayColumnNames(d);

        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/avebetwan.ttf");
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

        t.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth()));
        t.setTypeface(custom_font);

        Date date1 = new Date(2017,7,15);
        Event e = new Event(Color.RED, date1.getTime(),"text1");
        calendar.addEvent(e);

        calendar.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {
                t.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out! the problem was on this line:

```
Date date1 = new Date(2017,7,15);
```

The year should be 117 so it can refer to 2017 instead of 2017 which refers to 3917.
so that line of code should be like this:

```
Date date1 = new Date(117,7,15);
```